# unix script should run 9-21 hrs on weekdays (mon-sat) and on sunday (9-14 and 17-21hrs). It executes a procecudure in oracle

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

```
    START_DATE=`date '+%d%m%Y%H%M%S'`
DAYOFWEEK=$(date +"%u")
START_HOUR=$(date +"%H")


run_dt=`date '+%d%m%Y'`
run_hr=`date '+%H%M'`
echo 'run_hr' $run_hr

echo 'Shell script started'
echo ${START_DATE}
echo ${DAYOFWEEK}
echo ${START_HOUR}

while [ $run_hr -lt 21];
do
if [ $DAYOFWEEK = 1 ] || [ $DAYOFWEEK = 2 ] || [ $DAYOFWEEK = 3 ] || [ $DAYOFWEEK = 4 ] || [ $DAYOFWEEK = 5 ] || [ $DAYOFWEEK = 6 ]; then
echo 'inside while'

sqlplus -s xx/abcd<< END2
set timing on; 
select to_char(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyyhh24:mi') starttime from dual;
#exec my_proc();
select to_char(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyyhh24:mi') endtime from dual;
END2

sleep 120
let run_hr=`date '+%H%M'`
echo 'run_hr' $run_hr

elif [ $DAYOFWEEK = 7 ]; then
echo 'inside while on sunday'
sqlplus -s xx/abcd<< END2
set timing on; 
select to_char(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyyhh24:mi') starttime from dual;
#exec my_proc();
select to_char(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyyhh24:mi') endtime from dual;
END2

sleep 120
if [ $run_hr -eq 14 ]; then
sleep 10800else
let run_hr=`date '+%H%M'`
echo 'run_hr' $run_hr
echo 'Nothing'
fi
else
echo 'off'
fi
done

echo 'Exiting'
```

by keeping in the while loop the proc runs every time by initiating at 9am in the morning by a cron. but on sunday, i have to keep it for 3 hrs in sleep at 14:00 hrs. 
can you please tell me how to keep that to sleep for 3 hrs on sunday. 
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Some changes (did not test): Change `[ $DAYOFWEEK = 1 ]` into `[ $DAYOFWEEK -eq 1 ]` or use a case statement to switch over the values. Do not repeat code but use a function for it `my_sqlproc() { .... }`.  Don't add minutes to the run_hr variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to create another script (like a monitor script)that will execute the one that you posted:
monitor_script: put it in crontab and executed it every minute
procedure_script: your script

The purpose of monitor_script will be to:

1. check if your procedure_script is already "up & running"
2. execute the procedure_script if for some reason will goes down
3. Insert in monitor_script an "if" like:
   if  [ $DAYOFWEEK -eq 6 ] && [ $yourTimeVar == "14" ];then 
       sleep for 3hrs
   fi

Regards
C